# Grails maven project always ask me to upgrade to hibernate 2.2.3 to 2.2.1

Tags: maven, grails

The application did start with hibernate 2.2.1, but after we upgraded to hibernate 2.2.3, when ever I try to `run-app` get a prompt asking me if I would like to upgrade to version 2.2.1. If I say yes it then asks me, if I want upgrade to hibernate 2.2.3. This is breaking our promotion step, which the seeds the war into our company repository ..

Can any one please help

Thanks 
chris g

Comment: Do you have any plugin that has dependency to hibernate 2.2.1?

Comment: Follow @alidad 's question. Run dependency tree in maven for that particular group id and see where is it conflicting. `mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=org.grails.plugins -Dverbose` would give you all plugin artifact dependencies. Look for hibernate plugin conflicts and duplicates. Once older one (2.2.1) found, exclude that from the concerned dependency in pom file.